# Preventing extension of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

`preventExtensions()` method prevents *extensible* object from extending, isn't there way to redo it? Or isn't there a method or trick to convert *non-extensible* object to *extensible* object. I wanted to know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: You could probably create a copy of the object, and modify it. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/218196.

Comment: Set the old object as the prototype of a new object that you create. That'll let you maintain the integrity of the old one while inheriting from it. `var new_obj = Object.create(non_ext_obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can still modify the prototype, but not the object itself.

From MDN @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions:

> If there is a way to turn an extensible object to a non-extensible
>   one, there is no way to do the opposite in ECMAScript 5